# Get filtred data from table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, ngtable

I am using the AngularJs's ngTable Library to represent, sort and filter some data. I would like to use the filtred data but I couldn't figure out how to use the publishAfterDataFiltered() function, I always get an empty list. I didn't find any documentation for this function in particular.

```
ngEvents.onAfterDataFiltered(s.eventFunction, s, s.tableParams);
s.eventFunction = function() {
log.debug('dataChanged');
var newData = [];
ngEvents.publishAfterDataFiltered(s.tableParams, newData);
log.debug(newData.length);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out the solution for my problem.

To get the filtred data using the ngTable Library you simply need to use an EventListner and pass it to the onAfterDataFiltered function.

Example:

```
ngTableEventsChannel.onAfterDataFiltered(scope.listeningFunction, scope);
scope.listeningFunction= function(publisher, newData) {.......}
```